# 'The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

This question has been asked a lot of times. I think I solved my problem but since I am a beginner and still learning I need your reassurance.

I made a Extension method for the Logged In User But when I use it in my Controller it gives me the error in title.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.'

So I searched and experimented and adding this line of code
in the controller solved my problem.

```
db.Users.Attach(LoggedUser);
```

However I am not sure if my answer is correct, since a lot of answers about this question were to disable the Lazy Loading but I didn't end up using it.

Something like this.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
  public MyDbContext()
   {
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   }
}
```

Here is my Extension method:

```
 public static ApplicationUser GetLoggedInUserInDB(this System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal _User)
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            string userId = _User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var LoggedUser = db.Users.Find(userId);
            return LoggedUser;
        }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
public class MainPageController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Personal_Project/Main_Page_Personal_Project/UserUnfo")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(string))]
    [Authorize]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserInfo()
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var LoggedUser = User.GetLoggedInUserInDB();
            //db.Users.Attach(LoggedUser); // This is what I added to solve my problem.
            return Ok(new UserInfoModel
            {
                Name = LoggedUser.UserName,
                Reputation = LoggedUser.Reputation,
                UserLevel = LoggedUser.UserLevel
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So is 'My' solution here good? Just adding:

```
db.Users.Attach(LoggedUser);
```

Is it legit or this is not how we solve this problem. Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Added as requested:

StackTrace:

> ex.StackTrace "   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.get_Connection()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption
>   mergeOption)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Load(MergeOption
>   mergeOption)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem
>   propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean
>   mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.b__2(TProxy
>   proxy, TItem item)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_3D8410FBA1701532D53558B4E07B366CC45F4901DA609FCE10D652D704EEDD3C.get_CarGame()\r\n
>   at PersonalProject.Controllers.MainPageController.GetUserInfo() in
>   C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\PostPersonalProject\PersonalProject\PersonalProject\Controllers\MainPageController.cs:line
>   32"   string

Comment: Show full stack trace, please. Attaching `LoggedUser` to another context looks pointless.

Comment: I added the stack trace. And what do you mean by pointless? It works if I add it. Otherwise is doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting exception because of this: `get_CarGame()`.

Code inside original post doesn't match your actual code.

Somewhere inside *actual* `MainPageController.GetUserInfo` you're trying to read `ApplicationUser.CarGame`. And yes, this is lazy loading issue.

`GetLoggedInUserInDB` returns instance of proxy class, derived from `ApplicationUser`, and disposes original context. When `GetUserInfo` tries to get `CarGame` property value, proxy attempts to read it from database, using disposed context. As a result, exception is being thrown.

If you really need `CarGame` inside `UserInfoModel`:

- either turn off lazy loading as shown above, and use eager loading;
- use projection (that is, `Select`) to retrieve user info as `UserInfoModel` in place. In this case there is no need in `GetLoggedInUserInDB` method at all.

Anyway, attaching LoggedUser to another context is not a way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback and your time.